# When I use the Count method in Entity Framework, I get an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
string[] userIds = new string[0];
userIdsfromgrps = (from x in _context.GroupConfigs 
                   where Filter.name.Contains(x.GroupID.ToString()) 
                   select x.Value).ToArray();
((userIds.Count() > 0)
```

Comment: is error look like: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()'?

Answer (score 1):

This has **nothing** to do with Entity Framework.

You are converting the results into an **array** (*why?? Doesn't make any sense, really*) - and an array has no  `.Count()` method

To get the number of elements in an array, you must use the `.Length` property of the array:

```
string[] userIds = new string[0];
userIdsfromgrps = (from x in _context.GroupConfigs 
                   where Filter.name.Contains(x.GroupID.ToString()) 
                   select x.Value).ToArray();

int lengthOfArray = userIdsfromgrps.Length;
```

or you can just **not** convert the results to an array - and then use the `.Count()` method of Linq:

```
string[] userIds = new string[0];
var userIdsfromgrps = (from x in _context.GroupConfigs 
                       where Filter.name.Contains(x.GroupID.ToString()) 
                       select x.Value);

int countResults = userIdsfromgrps.Count();
```

Here, `userIdsfromgrps` will be an `IEnumerable<T>` with a type of `T` depending on what type your `x.Value` is.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably because of the third line in the code that is :

```
   where Filter.name.Contains(x.GroupID.ToString())
```

LINQ does not recognize "ToString()" method.